# DB - How do I roll back to a block height?

Tags: blockchain, parity, testnets, forks

I was informed on [this post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/26791/19308) that I was, indeed, on a fork. My client starts syncing and encounters a discrepancy with my local DB copy. My peers then vanish.

In my case, it would be a great hassle if I had to delete my entire DB copy, since it seems like I need to download GB of data again.

Fortunately, my client (Parity) kind of informs me of the block height where things went wrong.

```
2017-09-21 02:11:00  Syncing #1701857 4507…7213     0 blk/s    0 tx/s   0 Mgas/s      0+    0 Qed  #1701857    2/25 peers   516 KiB chain 66 MiB db 0 bytes queue 10 KiB sync  RPC:  1 conn,  4 req/s, 124 µs
2017-09-21 02:11:05  Stage 3 block verification failed for #1701858 (dec2…31af)
Error: Block(InvalidDifficulty(Mismatch { expected: 102912444, found: 102995535 }))
2017-09-21 02:11:35     0/25 peers   658 KiB chain 66 MiB db 0 bytes queue 54 KiB sync  RPC:  1 conn,  0 req/s, 100 µs
```

How do I roll back my DB copy to block height `1701857` so I can start syncing from that point?

Comment: That's not possible.